# Recognizing a Kanji?

Tags: kanji, katakana

One of my friends is translating some stuff, and he told me he needs "a second opinion for this one since he's having troubles to identify the first one".

I know the second one is だ, but I really can't identify the first one. I belived for a second it was Katakana, but I've checked both of my basic tables (my Japanese is extremely basic, worse than my English though), and I really can't find it.

I've tried to search words that end with だ, but that would be extremely slow, so I wanted to ask you guys, is this a Kanji? If so, which one?

[image: Is the first one a kanji?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually two words: one consisting of two characters in katakana (ダメ) and the other is in hiragana (だ) - together ダメだ. だめ is often written using katakana as ダメ.

The meaning depends on the context but could be "don't do it", "no", "it's not good", "you should not do it", "that's wrong".

Comment: I linked my friend this and he said it the translate now makes sense. Thank you very much!